# Selected Menu Item - Oslo MasterPage

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, master-page, css, html

I'm using SharePoint 2013, with the Oslo masterpage, and I've disabled the default navigations and create my own menu in the master page. The issue is that the menu doesn't show what page you are on. I want to add some css to the selected menu item, so that it indicates which page you are on. That would be easy if the menu was on each page, but it's not, it's on the masterpage and I'm not sure how to do it in the masterpage. My menu looks like this:

```
<nav id="menu" class="cl-effect-1" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; font-size:12px; background-color:#E3E3E3; border:1px solid; border-color:#33577F; border-radius:5px; float: right; margin-top:43px; margin-right: 84px;">
                            <a href="http://www.psi2000.com/home/default.aspx" style="font-size:15px; text-decoration: none; color:#33577F;">Home</a>
                            <a href="http://www.psi2000.com/about/default.aspx"style="font-size:15px; text-decoration: none; color:#33577F;">About Us</a>
                            <a href="http://www.psi2000.com/products/default.aspx"style="font-size:15px; text-decoration: none; color:#33577F;">Products</a>
                            <a href="http://www.psi2000.com/services/default.aspx"style="font-size:15px; text-decoration: none; color:#33577F;">Services</a>
                            <a href="http://www.psi2000.com/partners/default.aspx"style="font-size:15px; text-decoration: none; color:#33577F;">Partners</a>
                            <a href="http://www.psi2000.com/careers/default.aspx"style="font-size:15px; text-decoration: none; color:#33577F;">Careers</a>
                            <a href="http://www.psi2000.com/contact/default.aspx"style="font-size:15px; text-decoration: none; color:#33577F;">Contact Us</a>
                </nav>
```

Does anyone know how to do it in the masterpage?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hard Coded Navigation in Master Page - Active link not changing](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38024/hard-coded-navigation-in-master-page-active-link-not-changing)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put it in the masterpage (e.g. oslo.master) you have to choose the corresponding `.html` page (e.g. `oslo.html`). Sounds strange but this is the new way how it works with SharePoint Designer. You can also upload your custom html page, css and images to SharePoint with the Design Manager so that SP convert it to a masterpage

[Click here for an example](http://borderingdotnet.blogspot.de/2012/12/how-to-create-html-masterpage-for.html)

I've tested your html in `oslo.html` and it didn't work, because there is no blank space between `a.href` and style as of the second `a-tag`